# Android MapActivity on map movement

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

I want to monitor when someone moves to another place on the map in a `MapActivity` but I have no idea how to do that. Maybe some sort of OnMapChange() listener?

Comment: you might want to look into the `onDraw` method somewhere.. it will get called when the view needs to draw itself(like when the map is changing, moving, etc).  just a thought

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend the MapView class to add the necessary map change event.
http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/extending-mapview-to-add-a-change-event/

The post above shows you how to detect zooming and panning via virtually every way you can interact with the map: swipe (for pan), zoom control +/- (for zooming) and pinch (for combined pan and zoom).

Comment: Great project! Thank you for the link. I cleaned the repository somewhat in my [fork](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/MapChange/tree/cleaning).

Comment: I also have a small MapView class with three events, onClick, onPan and onZoom [on my blog here](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/android-map-view-with-pan-zoom-events/).