# Drop pin on map automatically when map is scrolled

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to develpe map like below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/location-based-apps

Currently i am Using Compute on map to capture scroll , i am using google api but its taking long to get responce data and drop pin

is there any native way to do this?

thanks

Comment: i fount this may b it help other

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8045313/1405903

Answer (score 2):

In android you need events fired on map change.
Have a look at: [How to catch that map panning and zoom are really finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567420/how-to-catch-that-map-panning-and-zoom-are-really-finished)

and http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/android-map-view-with-pan-zoom-events/

Comment: And with maps api v2 (MapFragments) you can use GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2