# How to handle onTouch event for map in Google Map API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

GoogleMap by default doesn't provide event for map drag start and drag stop. [I have already reported that problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702117/how-can-i-handle-map-move-end-using-google-maps-for-android-v2).

I want to make **custom** `handler` that will use plain `onTouch` event and combine it with `setOnCameraChangeListener`.

However i failed to find how I can access `onTouch` event of `GoogleMap` object. It doesn't provide such **callback**.

I wonder how can i handle onTouch event for map  in **Google Map API v2**?

Comment: what about overlays? Do they still have onTouchEvent() callback in API v2?

Comment: there is no overlay anymore. for marker and geomtry object they introduced separate methods.

Comment: why don't you use CameraChangeListener?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround for determining drag start and drag end events:

You have to extend `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`. In `onCreateView()` you have to wrap your `MapView` in a customized `FrameLayout` (in example below it is the class `TouchableWrapper`), in which you intercepts touch events and recognizes whether the map is tapped or not. If your `onCameraChange` gets called, just check whether the map view is pressed or not (in example below this is the variable `mMapIsTouched`).

Example code:

UPDATE 1:

- return original created view in `getView()`
- use `dispatchTouchEvent()` instead of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`

Customized FrameLayout:

```
private class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mMapIsTouched = true;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mMapIsTouched = false;
        break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    }
```

In your customized MapFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);

    mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
    mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);

    return mTouchView;
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return mOriginalContentView;
}
```

In your camera change callback method:

```
private final OnCameraChangeListener mOnCameraChangeListener = new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        if (!mMapIsTouched) {
            refreshClustering(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey @Alexey Zakharov, please have also a look into the Thread at Google Maps issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4636&q=apitype%3DAndroid2&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal%20Modified

Comment: @Alexey Zakharov i tried it but i get errors: the first error is on getActivity. could you post your customized MapFragment class declaration? (or entire code)

Comment: you need to extend SupportMapFragment or MapFragment.

Comment: Dear @AZ13 , I wrote it down this way but i get errors on getActivity(the code doesn't compiles): public class MyMapFragment extends MapFragment{ public View mOriginalContentView; public TouchableWrapper mTouchView; @ Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) { mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState); mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity()); ...continues..

Comment: @AZ13, I did use your solution as a base, but I improved on it by using a custom listener instead of a public static variable. Please see my solution below. Also, in your case using the mMapIsTouched boolean in the OnCameraChangeListener does not work most of the time, since the OnCameraChangeListener more often than not fires before the boolean value is updated, thus your code in the if will never fire off.

Comment: @AZ13, Awesome answer.  If you or anyone else is interested, I just created a library for managing a draggable overlay box using this answer as inspiration.  Find it here: https://github.com/mattlogan/DraggableOverlayBox

Comment: Hi @MattLogan Please check your github link and please provide a correct one.

Answer (score 7):

There is a simpler way to do this, handle your cases on `onCameraMoveStarted` listener like this

Below the code snippet

```
@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
    if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The user gestured on the map.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener
                            .REASON_API_ANIMATION) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The user tapped something on the map.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener
                            .REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The app moved the camera.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```