# Several threads for touch wrapper and Google Maps fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps, touchscreen

I have a following problem:

For my bachelor thesis I make a program that intercepts gestures from the touchscreen and zooms in Google Maps. The problem: How can I intercept the gestures was solved in [Google Maps Android API v2 - detect touch on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map-solved)?

Here is the complete code:

http://dimitar.me/how-to-detect-a-user-pantouchdrag-on-android-map-v2/

Because I have to zoom the map, I created an object Google Map in my Activity:

```
public class Zoom2Activity extends FragmentActivity implements UpdateMapAfterUserInterection
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    float xMid;
    float yMid;
    float zoom;
    double angle;
    int zoomCounter;
    boolean threadLifeFlag;
    PointFloat dSize= new PointFloat();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom2);
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();
    }

    // Implement the interface method

    //@Override
    public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(double angle, int zoomCounter) {
        // Here I zoom the map
        zoom = (float) (3+((zoomCounter*45+angle)/30));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
    }
}
```

Now the code is working, but the zoom is to slow during the touchscreen works. Then I take away the finger and the map zooms all the rest. I have no idea how can I make the own thread for the touchscreen or for view with map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection` is called on every `MotionEvent` I suggest calling `moveCamera` instead of `animateCamera`. It will zoom instantly to desired zoom level.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's as fast as I need!