# How to handle touch event on google map (MapFragment)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-touch-event

I am looking for a proper touch event that will be triggered when user touches the map (Google Maps Android API). Does anyone have an idea as to how to do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can directly add click listener and get position of touch on Map in form of Location.

```html
 map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                
              //Do what you want on obtained latLng
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried it. It's working.Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **SetOnMapClickListener**. Hope below demo code will help you to do so.

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onMapClick (LatLng latLng){

    latitude = latLng.latitude;
    longitude = latLng.longitude;

    myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
}
});
```