# OnTouch method within OnClick freezes MapView

Tags: android, onclick, android-mapview, arcgis, ontouchlistener

I have made a simple data collection App using ArcGis maps. The App works by the user clicking a button for what feature to add (point or polyline) and then touching the map view to add the point. However after the feature is added, the mapview freezes and the user can no longer zoom or pan the map, example code shown below:

```
private class existingOSDClicker implements Button.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mMapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                // Does something

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have issue something detect touch on may, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map