# Rotate map with one finger (using PAN gesture)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

i am using cordova-plugin-googlemaps(1.4.1) in ionic(3.4.0) and i am looking for a way to rotate the map with one finger.The plugin's documentation doesn't have any events for drag.

I found some custom code for android here [How can I rotate on Google Maps API(android) with only 1 finger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058495/how-can-i-rotate-on-google-maps-apiandroid-with-only-1-finger) but i am not very familiar with java,  i'll still be missing IOS functionality and this means i have to modify base plugin(i think). So I need something for Ionic's google maps plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: When you drag map they asking like drag with two finger something like that?

Comment: no, i am asking how to **rotate** map with **1 finger** like you rotate map in PokemonGo

Comment: cordova-plugin-googlemaps does not support it.