# Errors with Google maps on touchscreens

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been developing a small map application and it works wonderfully until I tried to use it with a touchscreen.  In chrome nothing happens, in firefox it sort of works, but in Internet explorer, the maps moves and but doesn't update and I get the following error in the console and is seen in the image below:

Script445: Object doesn't support this action
common.js (125,204)

[image: Google maps API issue]

Is touch just not supported in embedded google maps?

Comment: Maybe this helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map

Comment: @FeuFeuAngel I am unsure what that has to do with the web api, those answers are for android development.

Comment: This has suddenly happened to us as well. Even the Google Maps website has suddenly started failing on our touchscreen device (Windows 8.1, Internet Explorer). It seems Google may have deployed an update overnight that broke something? I'm not able to find many references to this error around the internet yet.

Comment: We have a workaround. We found that changing our script tag from `src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"` to `src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"`, to force using an older version of the API, works for our use-cases.

Comment: It's been raised as a bug; vote for it here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10413

Comment: @Roadrunner-EX Thanks for the tip, it worked like a charm.