# How to detect onTouch or Swipe on GoogleMap (V2)?

Tags: android, google-maps, ontouch

I want to get CameraPosition, i have coded as:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
           //code
        }
    });
```

But when i haven't touch map yet, it calls above method and give different camera position. For that i need to get touch event to check where user clicked on map or not.

I have used:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Log.d("OnMapClicked","Clicked");
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Log.d("OnMapClicked","Long Clicked");
        }
    });
```

But no use of above methods as it gives OnClick, i want to get on touch or on swipe.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I created the class MySupportMapFragment.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    public View mOriginalContentView;
    public TouchableWrapper mTouchView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);
        return mTouchView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mOriginalContentView;
    }
}
```

I even created the class TouchableWrapper.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

    public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  MainActivity.mMapIsTouched = true;
                  break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  MainActivity.mMapIsTouched = false;
                  break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

In the layout I declare it this way:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/buttonBar"
          class="com.myFactory.myApp.MySupportMapFragment"
/>
```

Just for test in the main Activity I wrote only the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public static boolean mMapIsTouched = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

you can follow this as well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14538765/6869491

Answer (score 0):

Add `<FrameLayout>` before your `<MapView>` in XML.
Enable touch to `<FrameLayout>`

Set on touch listener on your `<FrameLayout>`.