# Android Google Map | Two finger scrolling

Tags: android, google-maps, scroll, conditional-statements, custom-scrolling

I am working with Google Map,

My case is that I have a map fragment inside the **ScrollView** and I need to scroll the map only with **two finger** if user touches only one finger map should not work and normal Scroll View should work.

This is what i tried so far  -

```
transparent_image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                            showMessage("Double finger ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");

                            googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                            scroll_view.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            showMessage("Double finger ACTION_POINTER_UP");

                            googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);

                            scroll_view.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                            return true;

                        default:
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: There is another question similar to this one.
Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52730004) in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That behavior of native Android application you can achieve when:

1) disable `ScrollView` scrolling and enable `GoogleMap` scrolling when user placed two finger on `MapFragment`;

2) enable `ScrollView` scrolling and disable `GoogleMap` scrolling in other case.

For disabling/enabling `ScrollView` scrolling by condition, you need to extend `ScrollView` and override the `onTouchEvent()` method to return `false` when some condition is matched, for example, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763815/6950238) of [Josep Earl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290028/joseph-earl):

```
public class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean mScrollable = true;

    public LockableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mScrollable = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return mScrollable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
                if (mScrollable) return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
                return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
        // we are not scrollable
        if (!mScrollable) return false;
        else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Enable/disable scroll gestures at `GoogleMap` you can easily calling `setAllGesturesEnabled()` and `setScrollGesturesEnabled()` on `GoogleMap.getUiSettings()` object and for determining touches of two fingers on `MapFragment` you can use approach, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14538765/6950238) of community wiki:

```
public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

    private LockableScrollView mLockableScroll;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setGoogleMapAndScroll(GoogleMap googleMap, LockableScrollView lockableScroll) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mLockableScroll = lockableScroll;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                // UPDATE: add below line to disable zoom gesture
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
                mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(false);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
                // UPDATE: add below line to enable zoom gesture
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // UPDATE: add below line to disable zoom gesture
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // UPDATE: add below line to disable zoom gesture
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);
            break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

`MapFragment` in this case can be like that:

```
public class MultiTouchMapFragment extends MapFragment {
    public View mOriginalContentView;
    public TouchableWrapper mTouchView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);
        return mTouchView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mOriginalContentView;
    }
}
```

and `MainActivity` like that (there is no need to add marker on map - it's just for test):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private LockableScrollView mLockableScrollView;
    private MultiTouchMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLockableScrollView = (LockableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.lockable_scroll);
        mapFragment = (MultiTouchMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(48, 38);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title("Scroll"));
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

        mapFragment.mTouchView.setGoogleMapAndScroll(googleMap, mLockableScrollView);
    }
}
```

and, finally, `activity_main.xml` for `MainActivity`, for example, can be like this:

```
<[your_package_name].LockableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/lockable_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
            android:name="[your_package_name].MultiTouchMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</[your_package_name].LockableScrollView>
```

and that's it.

Comment: I am trying this.

Comment: Getting error on this line - 

     MultiTouchMapFragment mapFragment = (MultiTouchMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


ERROR - 

Error:(646, 96) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to MultiTouchMapFragment

Comment: Can you please check.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique  "zoom feature not working" - this is because `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);` diasbles all gestures. And `mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);` enables only scroll. You can use `.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true)` in `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` to enable it.

Comment: In which class can i find this method? dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event).

Comment: It's in `TouchableWrapper` class. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks, let me check :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng,
          gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
        });
```

For more details check this 
https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/smart-scrolling-comes-to-mobile-web-maps.html