# Android Google Map | Two finger scrolling inside tablayout

Tags: android

i have a google maps (fragment) inside a tablayout
With the tablayout i use a FragmentStateAdapter.
This allows me to nicly swipe through my tabs but (you can guess is) this swiping is working against me on the google maps fragment.

My idea was to setup 2 fiinger control for the map while the single finger could still service the tab-swiper.
i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320667/android-google-map-two-finger-scrolling) post and the answer of Andrii Omelchenko did give some real good pointers for a solution
However i do not have a scrollview and i cannot find any on...-methods in my ViewPagers2 and/or the FragmentStateAdapter to intercept the touch-events as is done in the scrollview.

Does anybody have an idea as how to handle the issue?