# Is it possible to listen to clicks in a small area of a marker in Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using Google Map in an Android app.

Google Map API provides a `setOnMarkerClickListener` so that we can do what we want when user clicks on a marker.

```
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            //Do my stuff here
        }
    });
```

However, my marker image is pretty large and I only want a small part of it to be clickable.

And it seems there is no method of `Marker` that returns its X Y position in its fragment.

So, is this actually feasible, assuming that I must use Google Map?

Comment: Please note that this is asked in an Android context.

Comment: however you may do this by click listener of google map. google providing onclick listener for google map.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava Do you mean OnMapClickListener? That returns a LatLng which is not applicable. User can zoom the map and the LatLng can differs largely, which has no relationship with the marker.

Comment: Perhaps a somewhat complex solution would be to colocate a transparent marker (alpha = 0) that has a small icon and associate the two markers using the 'tag' property and process the small marker as if the large marker was clicked.

Comment: The feature request for clickable marker area exists since 2013 (33 stars at the moment): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823783. However, it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task.

Comment: I found a way to manually handle clicks for markers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58140323/1499750