# How to adjust the shape of a polygon by moving its corners

Tags: android

I have an app with a map in which the user can add polygons calculating the area. I want the user to be able to adjust the shape of the polygon by moving its corners.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Google mapV2. People do it different ways, but I would implement [onClickListener() or OnTouchListener() interfaces just like the answers given in SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map) and update the LatLng of the polygon based on the new LatLng.