# OnTouchListener on com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there any way to handle `onTouchListener` on `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. Because, I tried the regular way as we do in case of a `View`but it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:clickable` attribute defines whether you want to allow user-interaction with the map. If this is `"false"` then touching the map does nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="API_KEY"
/>
```