# Draw rectangle on google map

Tags: java, android, touch, overlay, android-framelayout

I am extend a SupportMapFragment which contain google map here, I lay my google map on a frameLayout according to [How to handle onTouch event for map in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2). Ondraw()method is called , but the problem is rectangle is never been showed, even when I use setWillNotDraw(false); here.

I already got the right position of the rectangle, the only problem is it is not showed. Following is my most part of code:

**Add-on:When I remove the google map it works as I expect, actually the rectangle drawed on the background frameLayout, so it will be covered by the map, now the way I solve the question is add a image view as a rectangle and dynamic change its size when touch moving. I have no idea how to draw directly on the top of this viewgroup(framelayout) at the moment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    //stash reference to google map 
    mGoogleMap = getMap();
    //show the location
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
    mTouchView.addView(view);

    return mTouchView;
}

private class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

    //box is used to illustrate the drawing box, the painter is used to set the color of the box.
    private Box mCurrentBox = null;
    private Paint mBoxPaint;

    public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBoxPaint = new Paint();
        mBoxPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
    //  mBoxPaint.setStrokeMiter(20);
        mBoxPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);    
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // decide when the child should hold the motion event.
        return true;    //always let the relative layout to hold the motion event.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 mMapIsTouched = true;
                mCurrentBox = new Box(curr);//original code for draw Rectangle.
                Log.d(TAG, "action.down box is"+mCurrentBox);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.i(TAG, "action_move");
                if (mCurrentBox != null) {
                    mCurrentBox.setmCurrent(curr);
                    Log.d(TAG, "action.move box is"+mCurrentBox);
                    this.invalidate();  //TODO
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i(TAG, "action_up");
                mMapIsTouched = false;
                mCurrentBox = null;
                break;
                }
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float left = 0;
        float right = 0;
        float top = 0;
        float bottom = 0;
        if (mCurrentBox!=null) {
             left = Math.min(mCurrentBox.getmOrigin().x, mCurrentBox.getCurrent().x) ;
             right = Math.max(mCurrentBox.getmOrigin().x, mCurrentBox.getCurrent().x) ;
             top = Math.min(mCurrentBox.getmOrigin().y, mCurrentBox.getCurrent().y) ;
             bottom = Math.max(mCurrentBox.getmOrigin().y, mCurrentBox.getCurrent().y) ;
            canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mBoxPaint);
            }
        Log.i(TAG, "value is"+left+right+top+bottom);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may have to call `super.onDraw(canvas)` in your `onDraw` method

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the Map in a FrameLayout containing also a Drawable (your rectangle). In that way, once you find where the rectangle shall be, you could hide and show it without having to redraw it.

You can see [here](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I checked, it could be an alternative