# Google map V2 and navigation drawer

Tags: android, touch, google-maps-android-api-2, navigation-drawer

**PROBLEM**

I want to use `Google Map V2` in `Navigate Drawer` but I can't disable Navigate Drawer

and give touch handler to the map when it was touched. What should I do ???

**NOTE**

I have experience the similar problem like this before...

I would like to use `SeekBar` in `Navigate Drawer` and it can't scroll the SeekBar.

At that time, I can archive it by using `onTouchListener()` for SeekBar directly but now it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

So, here is my solution thank to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728035/2077479), I have adapt some code to archive my goal.

**STEP 1** :: create **TouchableWrapper** Class for `MySupportMapFragment`

**STEP 2** :: override `dispatchTouchEvent()` and do as the following

```
public  class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

    public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        ViewParent v;
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v = this.getParent();
                v.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v = this.getParent();
                v.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

**STEP 3** :: Create MySupportMapFragment Class and bind it with TouchableWrapper

```
public class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    public View mOriginalContentView;
    public TouchableWrapper mTouchView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);
        return mTouchView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mOriginalContentView;
    }

}
```

**STEP 4** :: Change your original xml Map Fragment to your custom one

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonBar"
    class="com.myFactory.myApp.MySupportMapFragment"
    />
```

Yeah, That's all now the `Google Map V2` can drag in the `Navigating Drawer`