# Opening navigation view detects map touch event automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, touch-event, android-navigationview

I am trying to move a map, and while moving, I have to manage the visibility of views.

When the map moves, I am able to handle the view's visibility but, the issues are:

1. While opening the navigation view, it detects a map touch event, and makes views visible/invisible.
2. While making views invisible (when the map is touched), the toolbar animates and hides, but the white view behind the toolbar, stays as it is.

Here is my [code snippet at CodeShare](https://codeshare.io/GbWbb2).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801813/google-map-v2-and-navigation-drawer this seems to be a great idea !!! try to use Supportmapfragment

Comment: one thing you can do is to maintain a flag for navigation view open/close, and according to it just disable map events.