# Android - Google Maps - How do I change the image of a marker and then back to the original image?

Tags: android, google-maps, selector, drawable, marker

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to change the drawable of a marker for when the user taps on it and then back to the original drawable when the user leaves his finger out of the screen.

I already know how to change the marker's drawable by using this:

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_drawable));
```

The problem is, where do I put that code exactly? If I put it inside the `onMarkerClick` callback then it's too late because that callback is fired after the user leaves his finger out of the screen (just like a normal click event in any view is fired only when the finger is let off the screen).

I've tried to set the drawable to a selector (as bellow) but it does not work (the code throws an exception):

```
final BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_selector);

final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(bitmapDescriptor)
                                                       .anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
                                                       .position(latLon);
```

Here is my_selector.xml (used above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_A" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_B" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_B" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Did you solve that?

Comment: @CodeHunter Nope, I was finally able to convince the design team to change their design slightly.

Comment: I see. Well, when I click the marker I am able to place a pressed icon but when I click another marker can't back the previous one default. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try `OnTouchListener` with maps.

On `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` you can set one background and on  `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you can set another background.

Please refer the link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I can't apply OnTouchListener on the Marker or on the Map. They are not common views.