# Positioning Dialog below Cluster in android

Tags: android, customdialog

I have a map in my app and in map I am creating a cluster of nearby requests locations.
Also,I am opening a custom dialog on ClusterClick which shows all the requests in that cluster.
All this is working perfectly. I only want to position dialog below/above cluster so that cluster is also visible with dialog.
Please tell me how to do it.
Adding code of creating cluster and dialog

cluster creation code

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(getActivity(), map, mClusterManager));
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    mClusterManager
            .setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
                    clickedCluster = cluster;
                    showPopUp(clickedCluster);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Dialog creation code

```
public void showPopUp(Cluster<MyItem>myItemCluster)
{
   dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_map);

    ListView lv_cluster= (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv_cluster);
    clusterItems.addAll(myItemCluster.getItems());
    ClusterAdapter clusterAdapter=new ClusterAdapter(getActivity(),clusterItems);
    lv_cluster.setAdapter(clusterAdapter);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            clusterItems.clear();
        }
    });
    //clusterItems.clear();
}
```

Comment: See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen

You can calculate x and y based on your cluster positions

Comment: Can you tell me how to get touch position on mapview inside fragment.I tried many things but they are not working

Comment: Check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2

Comment: using above method would I be able to get x and y coordinates in fragment?? I don't think we can