# Drag GoogleMaps-Marker via swiping over map

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a Google-Map + marker. I know how to make a marker draggable. The standard behaviour is to 'Long-Press' a marker and you can drag it.
What I want is to drag the marker by swiping over the map. It shouldn't be neccessary to hit the marker. User swipes over the map from left to right and simultanously the marker changes position from left to right where the distance equals swipe-length.

I can't find a suitable solution in the GM-API. Any ideas?

I'm using Swift 2.2

```
var marker: GMSMarker!   

func createMarker(title: String, target: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    marker = GMSMarker(position: target)
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.map = map
}

func activateDragMode() {
    marker.draggable = true
    map.settings.scrollGestures = false
    map.settings.zoomGestures = false
    map.settings.rotateGestures = false
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle onTouch event for map in Google Map API v2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2)

Comment: I couldn't transfer this to my problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GoogleMap-API doesn't provide the method I need. But i found a solution:

```
map.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panRecognition))
view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

func panRecognition(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if marker.draggable {
        let markerPosition = map.projection.pointForCoordinate(marker.position)
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(view)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
        let newPosition = CGPointMake(markerPosition.x + translation.x, markerPosition.y + translation.y)
        marker.position = map.projection.coordinateForPoint(newPosition)
    }
}
```

I had to deactivate 'consumesGesturesInView' to add my own PanGestureRecognizer, which manipulates the marker.

Comment: But what's "view" in view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.1**

By analysis on google api and other method, I did not get the proper one. The best and sweet answer for this question is by using pan gesture.

add the pan gesture to the mapView as

```
self.mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self. panHandler(_:)))
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Implementation of pan gesture method as

```
@objc private func panHandler(_ pan : UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if pan.state == .ended{
            let mapSize = self.mapView.frame.size
            let point = CGPoint(x: mapSize.width/2, y: mapSize.height/2)
            let newCoordinate = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: point)
            print(newCoordinate)
             //do task here
        }
}
```